# Is org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile#transferTo() method memory safe?

Tags: java, spring, multipart

**EDIT** I'm really sorry but I made a mistake by specifying the library. The one in the title is the correct one.

When using the `transferTo()` method of `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile`, should I be concerned of memory leaks?

Since I'm transferring a content I suppose there's a stream to manage. By checking the documentation I didn't find any reference, but I neither find any clear statement that the stream management is handled by the library.

Comment: No, there's a *channel* to manage. Two of them. Both yours. I don't really understand what you think might be 'memory unsafe' about it, or indeed what that really means.

Comment: I mean, when you use streams, you must explicitly open and close them. You must handle them very carefully because the worst thing in the world are streams left open. They will lead you towards the dreaded PermGen space exception and this may happen for a number of tricky situations. What I'm asking is: by doing `file.transferTo(...)` should I look for a way to close the established channel or is the method itself that takes care of this aspect?

Answer (score 1):

transferTo and transferFrom are part of Java NIO.

There are two overloaded methods

One is a native implementation delegated to the kernel.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java#FileChannelImpl.transferTo0%28int%2Clong%2Clong%2Cint%29

The other uses WritableByteChannel.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java#FileChannelImpl.transferTo%28long%2Clong%2Cjava.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel%29

Here is an oracle blog post which explains the difference between streams and channels

https://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio

As long as your "channel" objects are properly used/closed. I don't think there is any explicit management of memory.